# iOS enumerateChildNodeswithName to access ALL physics bodies

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I'm writing a helper method to display a summary of all of the physics interactions (collisions and contacts) in an SpriteKit app on iOS.

I have a simple scene, with a boundary (from  `self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame)`) and 3 simple shapes (2 squares and a circle) wich are added to the scene via `addChild()`

In my helper function, I want to search all nodes and if they have a physicsBody, print their category, collision and contactTest bit masks.

If I code the following:

```
enumerateChildNodesWithNeme("*") { node, _ in {
   print("Node: \(node.name)")
}
```

then I only get the 3 shapes listed:

```
Node: Optional("shape_blueSquare")
Node: Optional("shape_redCircle")
Node: Optional("shape_purpleSquare")
```

My scene's physicsBody is not returned. But if I use:

```
enumerateChildNodesWithNeme("..") { node, _ in {
   print("Node: \(node.name)")
}
```

then I get:

```
Node: Optional("shape_edge")
```

If I use:

```
enumerateChildNodesWithNeme("..//") { node, _ in {
   print("Node: \(node.name)")
}
```

I get nothing, whereas I thought this would move up the node tree to the scene and then recursively return all children. The search argument `"//*"` also returns just the 3 children.

All the time, the node count displayed by `skView.showNodecount = true` is `4`.

So my question is: Is there a search argument for enumerateChildNodesWithName that will return all the nodes in a scene (including the scene itself) or have I misunderstood the relationship between the scene and it's children, in that a single search cannot search both? It may be the latter, as `print("\(parent.children)")` returns `nil`, when I was expecting to see `self` or some variation of such.

Comment: If this is the way that it works, and my code will find all physics bodies other that the scene's physics body, then that's fine - I can just handle that separately. I just want to make sure that I'm not potentially missing anything else.

Comment: Printing something like `print("\(parent.children)")` will always end up with nil. I assume that here, implicit self is a `GameScene` or something like that. You are getting nil, because ([according to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/)), the scene is a root node, so it can't have a parent. For example, you can't remove the scene from its parent (the `self.parent` property is always `nil`, when self is a  current scene) thus something like `self.removeFromParent()` has no effect.

Comment: @Whirlwind - that makes sense - thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Have you tried the code I've posted as an answer ? Does it work for you ?

Comment: I did and it did - just marked up your answer - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
enumerateChildNodesWithName("//.") { (node, _) -> Void in
     print("Node: \(node.name)")
}
```

About `//` :

> When placed at the start of the search string, this specifies that the
>   search should begin at the root node and be performed recursively
>   across the entire node tree.

About `.` :

> Refers to the current node.

Also this might work for you as well (if you want to find all physics bodies within a given rectangle):

```
self.physicsWorld.enumerateBodiesInRect(frame) { (body, _) -> Void in
    print(body.node?.name)
}
```

Comment: Just tried that on the train home and it worked - thanks very much . Not convinced that the description of the // and . operators is logical in this situation though.